# Kubernetes Kube-Proxy Server: Can it run without iptables' nat module?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, iptables, kube-proxy

**Background**:
In our environment, iptables' nat module is disabled. So I must use '-b=none --iptables=false' to start docker daemon and always add '--net host' when using 'docker run' command.

The same problem arising when using kubernetes.
When I try to start the 'kube-proxy' service, I got an error:

```
> F0822 14:32:49.065506   29630 server.go:101] Unable to create proxer:
> failed to initialize iptables: error creating chain
> "KUBE-PORTALS-CONTAINER": exit status 3: iptables v1.4.21: can't
> initialize iptables table `nat': Table does not exist (do you need to
> insmod?) Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

Is there a way to bypass this?

Answer (score 0):

Kube-proxy makes heavy use of IPtables, even in `userspace` mode. I'm afraid you won't be able to run a Kubernetes node on a machine where IPtables is disabled completely.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.